The Use of the Inverse Function Theorem in the Proofs of the Implicit Function Theorem and The Rank Theorem
I've been wondering if there is a corollary of the Inverse Function Theorem (InFT) used often, but implicitly, in proofs of other theorems. $\def\RR{\mathbb{R}} \def\f{\varphi}$ I include the outline of two proofs that use the InFT very similarly. My precise question is if there is some corollary of the InFT that would greatly simplify the following two proofs. $\def\RR{\mathbb{R}} \def\f{\varphi}$

A note on notation: I often write $f:\RR^n\to\RR^m$ for a function that is defined only on a subset of $\RR^n$; the outline would become rather long otherwise.
Example 1: a standard proof (see Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds 2-12) of the Implicit Function Theorem (ImFT) for a function $f:\RR^{n+m}\to\RR^m$ begins with the following steps:

'Extend' $f$ into the function $F:\RR^n\times\RR^m\to\RR^n\times\RR^m:(x,y)\mapsto (x,f(x,y)).$
Apply the InFT to $F$.
Note $F^{-1}$ has the form $(x,y)\mapsto (x,G(x,y))$ for some $C^k$ function $G:\RR^{n+m}\to\RR^m$.
The function we've been looking for is $g:\RR^m\to\RR^m:x\mapsto G(x,0)$.

Example 2: a standard proof (see Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds 4.12) of the Rank Theorem for a smooth function $F:\RR^m\to\RR^n$ of constant rank $r$ follows the next steps:

Write the local representation of $f$ as $f(Q(x,y),R(x,y))$ for smooth maps $Q:\RR^n\to\RR^r$ and $R:\RR^m\to\RR^{n-r}$.

'Extend' $Q$ into the function $\f:\RR^m\to\RR^m:(x,y)\mapsto (Q(x,y),y)$.

Apply the InFT to $\f$.

Note $\f^{-1}$ has the form $(x,y)\mapsto (A(x,y),y)$ for some smooth function $A:\RR^m\to\RR^r$.

The function $S:\RR^r\to\RR^r:y\mapsto R(A(x,y),0)$ is then used to finish the proof.


At first I thought that the corollary was the ImFT itself. However, in the second proof, it is the function $y\mapsto A(0,y)$ (not $S$) that has the properties of the ImFT.
Though I don't know if it's necessary, I include a picture of (the relevant part of) these two proofs below; for the Rank Theorem assume for simplicity that $M=\RR^m$ and $N=\RR^n$ with their standard smooth manifold structure.








I cannot figure out what exactly your question is! Please state the corollary that you believe is intermediary between InFT and IFT. And maybe explain how it would simplify the proof of IFT.
